# How to create a simple marker/highlighter, taking into account tags collision intervals and block level elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highlight, textselection

I'm trying to create a simple tool that allows the user to select a piece of text on a page so that he/she can **highlight what has been selected**. I found that I could start solving this problem by using the [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) API. Basically, to highlight a snippet the following code is being used:

```js
function highlight(hl){
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if(!sel || sel.iscollapsed || sel.rangeCount <= 0) return;
  
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  var hlWrap = document.createElement("span");
  hlWrap.classList.add(`highlighter-${hl}`);
  range.surroundContents(hlWrap);
}
```

```css
.highlighter-1 ,
.highlighter-2 {
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  display: inline;
}

.highlighter-1 { background: rgb(254, 255, 171); }
.highlighter-2 { background: rgb(255, 171, 171); }
```

```html
<button onclick="highlight(1)">HL1</button>
<button onclick="highlight(2)">HL2</button>
<div class="content">
<p>Phasellus dapibus congue nisi et dignissim. Mauris id pharetra elit, sit amet sagittis lorem. <span class="highlighter-1">Suspendisse
            sed quam in mi facilisis maximus.</span> Donec aliquet maximus risus sed cursus. Proin commodo interdum tortor, et
            mollis tellus luctus non. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
            mus <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2Ff%2Ff3%2FEmoji_u1f435.svg%2F768px-Emoji_u1f435.svg.png&f=1&nofb=1" width="24px">. 
            <strong>Phasellus ornare sodales magna, id egestas nisi dictum quis.</strong> Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum
            primis in faucibus. <span class="highlighter-1">Phasellus non nibh sit</span> amet elit dignissim ullamcorper.</p>
<p>Nam in turpis viverra, cursus urna eget, vulputate sapien. Curabitur et mi convallis, sollicitudin felis
            <span class="highlighter-2">vitae, vestibulum sapien. Etiam a convallis sem, nec placerat leo. Curabitur rutrum magna enim,</span> eget blandit
            ipsum accumsan vel. Duis auctor tellus enim, id mollis risus egestas at. Cras at neque leo. Proin pretium
            semper facilisis. </p></div>
```

This works, but with severe limits:

1. I can't cross highlights. That is, if I have a highlighted a section/interval/range,
   I cannot highlight a part of it again.
2. I cannot select and highlight portions/ranges/sections that involve elements from
   different block levels. For example, start a selection in one
   paragraph and end it in another.

**NOTE:** The previous two items return me the following error:

```js
Paused on exception
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

3. Its possible to apply one highlight on top of another (involving another one) without removing the previous one. The result can be tags involving others, infinitely.

I would also like to know how it is possible:

1. Delete highlighted sections without removing everything but just
   what is selected.
2. Add highlights of the same type if intervals collide in any way. That is, I want to mix / merge highlights that are the same type, and that represent one if they are added together. For example:

```html
Mauris <span class="highlighter-1">id</span><span class="highlighter-1"> pharetra elit, sit amet</span> sagittis lorem.
```

I am 3 days looking for this over the internet, and unfortunately I did not find anything. It seems every search engine (here on stack, google, duckduckgo, youtube, wikipedia) presents me something with similar terms, but referring to other subjects. It is very frustrating. English is not my native language, and I don't think I know the right terms to be weighed. Please, I don't know what to do anymore, and I would very much like someone to at least give me any light.

If the solution is in pure JavaScript or jQuery, it doesnt matter, both are very much welcome.

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/SmartTeleMax/MaSha